# Why is the response body empty when using HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, http, servlets

Here is my code for a servlet doGet() method:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String admin = "true";
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
    writer.write(admin);
    writer.flush();
}
```

It is properly setting the content type and character encoding, but the response body is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check if there is an [exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter())

Comment: resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

Comment: It works fine for me which makes me think that this is not your actual code but some oversimplified version. How do you use your code? Are there maybe some redirections?

Comment: This is the actual code. I once was trying debugging and somehow saw the expected output in the response body during the process but I have not been able to replicate that.

Comment: Works for me too. What http client are you using? How are you looking for the response content?

Comment: What's in 'admin'? Are you sure it isn't empty?

Answer (score 0):

Use this way,

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    String admin = "true";

     resp.setContentType("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
     resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

     PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
     try {

        out.println(admin);
     } finally {            
        out.close();
     }
}
```

Comment: What will this change?